# Is there any Python function that will format a measurement and an uncertainty parenthetically?

Tags: python, formatting

For example, say I have these numbers from calculations:

17.969860 with uncertainty 5.966e-05

0.01202 with uncertainty 0.001749

and I want to format them in this way instead:

17.96986(6), 0.012(2)

Does any sort of function exist that automatically formats measurements with uncertainties in this way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to code it yourself:

```
import math
def str_with_err(value, error):
    digits = -int(math.floor(math.log10(error)))
    return "{0:.{2}f}({1:.0f})".format(value, error*10**digits, digits)

print str_with_err(17.969860, 5.966e-05)
# 17.96986(6)
print str_with_err(0.01202, 0.001749)
# 0.012(2)
```

Comment: Almost there! In case `print( str_with_err(75.124, 14.2354) )` output should be `75(14)`. If error starts with '1' then it should be rounded to two digits. There is also a problem if error is 1.2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

### uncertainties

The [uncertainties](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) package is an established package for handling error propagation. It also supports formatting value/uncertainty pairs as you describe.

```
from uncertainties import ufloat

print(f'{ufloat(17.969860, 5.966e-05):.1uS}')
# 17.96986(6)

print(f'{ufloat(0.01202, 0.001749):.1uS}')
# 0.012(2)
```

### sciform

I am developing a lighter weight package dedicated to scientific number formatting called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which can also do this formatting

```
from sciform import SciNum

print(f'{SciNum(17.969860, 5.966e-05):!1()}')
# 17.96986(6)

print(f'{SciNum(0.01202, 0.001749):!1()}')
# 0.012(2)
```

or using a formatter object (which exposes more options and may be more readable than using the [format specification mini-language](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fsml.html)):

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    paren_uncertainty=True,
    ndigits=1,
)

print(sform(17.969860, 5.966e-05))
# 17.96986(6)

print(sform(0.01202, 0.001749))
# 0.012(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function that should handle all cases and does not rely on external modules except for `numpy`.
Note that it does not comply with @drgrujic's comment *"if error starts with '1' then it should be rounded to two digits"* because that is not something I like, but the error precision can be specified.

```
import numpy as np

def value_with_error(val, err, precision=2):
    """String with value and error in parenthesis with the number of digits given by precision."""
    # Number of digits in the error
    err_decimals = precision - int(np.floor(np.log10(err) + 1))
    # Output error with a "precision" number of significant digits
    err_out = round(err, err_decimals)
    # Removes leading zeros for fractional errors
    if err_out < 1:
        err_out = int(round(err_out * 10**err_decimals))
        err_format = 0
    else:
        err_format = int(np.clip(err_decimals, 0, np.inf))

    # Format the value to have the same significant digits as the error
    val_out = round(val, err_decimals)
    val_format = int(np.clip(err_decimals, 0, np.inf))

    return f'{val_out:.{val_format}f}({err_out:.{err_format}f})'
```