# Print measurement uncertainty after number

Tags: python

I have a lot of measurements, with measurement uncertainties. To speed up the process of reporting all the measurements and their uncertainties, I'm writing a script to print them for me.

For example, when I have measurement x = 0.012345 with uncertainty dx = 0.000321, I want my python script to print '0.0123(3)', with (3) being the uncertainty on the last digit of the rounded x

I feel like this should be very easy, but so far, I'm coming up with incredibly ugly solutions, iterating over numbers as a string. What would be a good pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the python library uncertanties?
https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any Python function that will format a measurement and an uncertainty parenthetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031402/is-there-any-python-function-that-will-format-a-measurement-and-an-uncertainty-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from math import log10, floor

x = 0.012345
dx = 0.000321

print('{:.{prec}f}({:.0f})'.format(x, floor(dx / (10**floor(log10(dx)))), prec=-floor(log10(dx))))
```

This code prints

```
0.0123(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
print("{:.4f}({:.0f})".format(x, dx*10**4))
```

However that will only work if your error is in the order of 10**-4 otherwise it will output more numbers and if it is smaller it will output `(0)`. S you might have to deal with the powers of your values. So this works for your specific example. Not sure how flexible it is supposed to be. BUt this could be a start for an idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very clever solution from Yaroslav Kornachevskyi, I wrote a little function to do this for all numbers, rounding correctly. Probably nobody will ever use this but me:

```
from math import log10, floor, ceil

x = 0.012345
dx = 0.0000968

def get_number(x, dx):
    """ Returns a string of the measurement value"""
    """ together with the measurement error"""
    """ x: measurement value"""
    """ dx: measurment error"""

    # Power of dx
    power_err = log10(dx)

    # Digits of dx in format a.bcd
    n_err = dx / (10**floor(power_err))

    # If the second digit in dx is >=5
    # round the 1st digit in dx up
    if n_err % 1 >= 0.5:
        # If the first digit of dx is 9
        # the precision is one digit less
        if int(n_err) == 9: 
        err = 1
        # The precision of x is determined by the precision of dx
        prec=int(-floor(log10(dx))) - 1           
    else:
        err = ceil(n_err)
        # The precision of x is determined by the precision of dx
        prec=int(-floor(log10(dx)))
    # Otherwise round down
    else:      
        err = floor(n_err) 
        # The precision of x is determined by the precision of dx
        prec=int(-floor(log10(dx)))

    return '{:.{prec}f}({:.0f})'.format(x, err, prec = prec)

print(get_number(x, dx))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a PyPi package called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that can format value/uncertainty pairs as requested. Many other scientific formatting options are available as well:

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(ndigits=1, paren_uncertainty=True)

x = 0.012345
dx = 0.000321
x_str = sform(x, dx)

print(x_str)
# 0.0123(3)
```